# Differential Vector Element

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, indefinite-integrals

I am a little confused about differential element notations. Say we have a function $f$ defined on a 3D space. Would the following notations be identical?

$$\int f(\vec{x}) \, d\vec{x}$$

$$\int f(x_{1},x_{2},x_{3}) \, d^3x$$

Intuitively the equivalence makes sense: if we sum over all combinations of $x_{1},x_{2},x_{3}$, we sum over all possible vectors. But notation wise how can we convert $d\vec{x}$ to $d^3x$. In certain cases would it be better to use one notation over the other?

Comment: I would not consider them identical. The first one I would think has a vector measure, while the second would be an ordinary integral over 3D space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have never seen $d^3x$ in this context and TBH I'm not sure it's accurate.  Technically it would be $(dx)^3$ but even that isn't correct because your variables in the second form are $x_1, x_2, x_3$.

What I've seen and what I use is $$ \iiint f(x_1, x_2, x_3) \, dx_1 \, dx_2 \, dx_3.$$

It's also possible, although I think uncommon and perhaps informal, to say $$\displaystyle \int f(x_1,x_2,x_3) \, dx_1\, dx_2\, dx_3.$$  I think I've only seen this in the context of measure theory.

> But notation wise how can we convert $d\vec{x}$ to $d^3x$.

If $\vec x = \langle x_1, x_2, x_3 \rangle$, then $d\vec x$ can be replaced with $dx_1 \, dx_2 \, dx_3$ in the integral.  For definite integrals you'll need to be careful about the order in which those three are written.

> In certain cases would it be better to use one notation over the other?

It's really just personal preference as to which one you use, but I think the form with $x_1, x_2, x_3$ is generally better if you want to emphasize or highlight either the three different variables in use or the order in which the integrations are to be done.

Comment: It's quite common in physics to write $d^3x$ to make it clear that it's an integral in $\mathbb R^3$.